# Logstash not creating index on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, ubuntu-14.04, logstash, kibana, system-administration

I'm trying to setup a ELK stack on EC2, Ubuntu 14.04 instance. But everything install, and everything is working just fine, except for one thing.

Logstash is not creating an index on Elasticsearch. Whenever I try to access Kibana, it wants me to choose an index, from Elasticsearch.

Logstash is in the ES node, but the index is missing. Here's the message I get:

`"Unable to fetch mapping. Do you have indices matching the pattern?"`

Am I missing something out? I followed this tutorial: [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-4-on-ubuntu-14-04)

**EDIT:**
Here's the screenshot of the error I'm facing: 
[image: Logstash missing Indices in ES (Kibana4)]
Yet another screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to identify the issue. For some reason, the port 5000 is being accessed by another service, which is not allowing us to accept any incoming connection. So all your have to do is to edit the logstash.conf file, and change the port from `5000` to `5001` or anything of your convenience.

Make sure all of your logstash-forwarders are sending the logs to the new port, and you should be good to go. If you have generated the `logstash-forwarder.crt` using the FQDN method, then the logstash-forwarder should be pointing to the same FQDN and not an IP.

Answer (score 8):

I got identical results on Amazon AMI (Centos/RHEL clone)

In fact *exactly* as per above… **Until** I injected some data into Elastic - this creates the first `day` index - then Kibana starts working. My simple `.conf` is:

```
input {
  stdin {
      type => "syslog"
    }
}
output {
  stdout {codec => rubydebug }
   elasticsearch {
          host => "localhost"
          port => 9200
          protocol => http
       }
}
```

then

```
cat /var/log/messages | logstash -f your.conf
```

Why `stdin` you ask? Well it's not super clear anywhere (also a new Logstash user - found this very unclear) that Logstash will never terminate (e.g. when using the `file` plugin) - it's designed to keep watching.

But using stdin - Logstash will run - send data to Elastic (which creates index) then go away.

If I did the same thing above with the `file` input plugin, it would never create the index - I don't know why this is.

Comment: Thanks for the help man. I asked the same question on Reddit, and looks like I'm getting somewhere with solving the issue: http://www.reddit.com/r/devops/comments/30nvu0/struggling_to_make_logstash_create_an_index_on/

Comment: so the output of:
curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
is blank ( change 9200 to whatever port you are using )

Answer (score 0):

Is this Kibana3 or 4?

If it's Kibana4, can you click on settings in the top-line menu, choose indices and then make sure that the index name contains 'logstash-*', then click in the 'time-field' name and choose '@timestamp'

I've added a screenshot of my settings below, be careful which options you tick.

[image: logstash settings]

Comment: Sorry. i must have mentioned it. It's Kibana 4. I tried doing that, but it threw me more errors. Will update the question with those errors. :)

Comment: Try unticking 'use event times to create index names'

Comment: Have updated the screenshot for you! Its still not able to find or create an index.

Comment: Assuming this is on a linux server, what happens if you run 'curl localhost:9200' on the elasticsearch server, specifically what version of elasticsearch does it see?

Comment: Yes. I'm on a Linux server. And I'm using ES version 1.4.4